# How to overwrite Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation\AbstractAggregateCalculator?

Tags: magento2, tax, tax-class, tax-calculation

I was facing an issue in tax calculation after discount for that i need to do code change from

```
//TODO: handle originalDiscountAmount
$taxableAmount = max($rowTotalInclTax - $discountAmount, 0);
$rowTaxAfterDiscount = $this->calculationTool->calcTaxAmount(
    $taxableAmount,
    $rate,
    true,
    false
);
$rowTaxAfterDiscount = $this->roundAmount(
    $rowTaxAfterDiscount,
    $rate,
    true,
    self::KEY_REGULAR_DELTA_ROUNDING,
    $round,
    $item
);
// Set discount tax compensation
$discountTaxCompensationAmount = $rowTax - $rowTaxAfterDiscount;
$rowTax = $rowTaxAfterDiscount;
```

to

```
$taxableAmount = max($rowTotal - $discountAmount, 0);
$discountTaxCompensationAmount = 0;
$rowTax = $taxableAmount * ($rate / 100);
```

in vendor/magento/module-tax/Model/Calculation/AbstractAggregateCalculator.php:49

For that change i use preference in my custom module

```
  <preference for="Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation\AbstractAggregateCalculator" type="Custom\Tax\Model\Calculation\AbstractAggregateCalculator" />
```

and overwritten the file

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Custom\Tax\Model\Calculation;

use Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsItemInterface;

/**
 * Abstract aggregate calculator.
 */
abstract class AbstractAggregateCalculator extends \Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation\AbstractAggregateCalculator
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function calculateWithTaxInPrice(QuoteDetailsItemInterface $item, $quantity, $round = true)
    {
        $taxRateRequest = $this->getAddressRateRequest()->setProductClassId(
            $this->taxClassManagement->getTaxClassId($item->getTaxClassKey())
        );
        $rate = $this->calculationTool->getRate($taxRateRequest);
        $storeRate = $this->calculationTool->getStoreRate($taxRateRequest, $this->storeId);

        $discountTaxCompensationAmount = 0;
        $applyTaxAfterDiscount = $this->config->applyTaxAfterDiscount($this->storeId);
        $discountAmount = $item->getDiscountAmount();

        // Calculate $rowTotalInclTax
        $priceInclTax = $this->calculationTool->round($item->getUnitPrice());
        $rowTotalInclTax = $priceInclTax * $quantity;
        if (!$this->isSameRateAsStore($rate, $storeRate)) {
            $priceInclTax = $this->calculatePriceInclTax($priceInclTax, $storeRate, $rate, $round);
            $rowTotalInclTax = $priceInclTax * $quantity;
        }
        $rowTaxExact = $this->calculationTool->calcTaxAmount($rowTotalInclTax, $rate, true, false);
        $deltaRoundingType = self::KEY_REGULAR_DELTA_ROUNDING;
        if ($applyTaxAfterDiscount) {
            $deltaRoundingType = self::KEY_TAX_BEFORE_DISCOUNT_DELTA_ROUNDING;
        }
        $rowTax = $this->roundAmount($rowTaxExact, $rate, true, $deltaRoundingType, $round, $item);
        $rowTotal = $rowTotalInclTax - $rowTax;
        $price = $rowTotal / $quantity;
        if ($round) {
            $price = $this->calculationTool->round($price);
        }

        //Handle discount
        if ($applyTaxAfterDiscount) {
            //TODO: handle originalDiscountAmount
            $taxableAmount = \max($rowTotal - $discountAmount, 0);
            $discountTaxCompensationAmount = 0;
            $rowTax = $taxableAmount * ($rate / 100);
        }

        // Calculate applied taxes
        /** @var  \Magento\Tax\Api\Data\AppliedTaxInterface[] $appliedTaxes */
        $appliedRates = $this->calculationTool->getAppliedRates($taxRateRequest);
        $appliedTaxes = $this->getAppliedTaxes($rowTax, $rate, $appliedRates);

        return $this->taxDetailsItemDataObjectFactory->create()
            ->setCode($item->getCode())
            ->setType($item->getType())
            ->setRowTax($rowTax)
            ->setPrice($price)
            ->setPriceInclTax($priceInclTax)
            ->setRowTotal($rowTotal)
            ->setRowTotalInclTax($rowTotalInclTax)
            ->setDiscountTaxCompensationAmount($discountTaxCompensationAmount)
            ->setAssociatedItemCode($item->getAssociatedItemCode())
            ->setTaxPercent($rate)
            ->setAppliedTaxes($appliedTaxes);
    }
    /**
     * Round amount
     *
     * @param float $amount
     * @param null|float $rate
     * @param null|bool $direction
     * @param string $type
     * @param bool $round
     * @param QuoteDetailsItemInterface $item
     * @return float
     */
    abstract protected function roundAmount(
        $amount,
        $rate = null,
        $direction = null,
        $type = self::KEY_REGULAR_DELTA_ROUNDING,
        $round = true,
        $item = null
    );
}
```

But the changes are not reflecting, i think abstract class cannot be overwritten, can some one suggest a solution or fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied patch like this for quick fix as it is an urgency in my project, but still waiting for some other approach

```
diff --git a/vendor/magento/module-tax/Model/Calculation/AbstractAggregateCalculator.php b/vendor/magento/module-tax/Model/Calculation/AbstractAggregateCalculator.php
--- a/vendor/magento/module-tax/Model/Calculation/AbstractAggregateCalculator.php
+++ b/vendor/magento/module-tax/Model/Calculation/AbstractAggregateCalculator.php
@@ -49,24 +49,9 @@
         //Handle discount
         if ($applyTaxAfterDiscount) {
             //TODO: handle originalDiscountAmount
-            $taxableAmount = max($rowTotalInclTax - $discountAmount, 0);
-            $rowTaxAfterDiscount = $this->calculationTool->calcTaxAmount(
-                $taxableAmount,
-                $rate,
-                true,
-                false
-            );
-            $rowTaxAfterDiscount = $this->roundAmount(
-                $rowTaxAfterDiscount,
-                $rate,
-                true,
-                self::KEY_REGULAR_DELTA_ROUNDING,
-                $round,
-                $item
-            );
-            // Set discount tax compensation
-            $discountTaxCompensationAmount = $rowTax - $rowTaxAfterDiscount;
-            $rowTax = $rowTaxAfterDiscount;
+            $taxableAmount = max($rowTotal - $discountAmount, 0);
+            $discountTaxCompensationAmount = 0;
+            $rowTax = $taxableAmount * ($rate / 100);
         }
 
         // Calculate applied taxes
```

Comment: This ways is better than other answers.

Answer (score 3):

Right, you can't overwrite an Abstract class, overwrite its child classes instead.

There are 2 child classes of `Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation\AbstractAggregateCalculator`:

- `Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation\RowBaseCalculator`
- `Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation\TotalBaseCalculator`

To achieve your requirements, take the following steps:
Assume your vendor name is **Custom** and your module name is **Tax**.

Step 1: Create registration.php:
File path: `app/code/Custom/Tax/registration.php`

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Custom_Tax', __DIR__);
```

Step 2: Create module.xml:
File path: `app/code/Custom/Tax/etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Custom_Tax">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Tax"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Step 3: Create di.xml:
File path: `app/code/Custom/Tax/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation\TotalBaseCalculator" type="Custom\Tax\Model\Calculation\TotalBaseCalculator" />
    <preference for="Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation\RowBaseCalculator" type="Custom\Tax\Model\Calculation\RowBaseCalculator" />
</config>
```

Step 4: Create TotalBaseCalculator file.
File path: `app/code/Custom/Tax/Model/Calculation/TotalBaseCalculator.php`

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Tax\Model\Calculation;

use Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsItemInterface;

class TotalBaseCalculator extends \Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation\TotalBaseCalculator
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function calculateWithTaxInPrice(QuoteDetailsItemInterface $item, $quantity, $round = true)
    {
        // Your overwrite code goes here
    }
}
```

Step 5: Create RowBaseCalculator file.
File path: `app/code/Custom/Tax/Model/Calculation/RowBaseCalculator.php`

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Tax\Model\Calculation;

use Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsItemInterface;

class RowBaseCalculator extends \Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation\RowBaseCalculator
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function calculateWithTaxInPrice(QuoteDetailsItemInterface $item, $quantity, $round = true)
    {
        // Your overwrite code goes here
    }
}
```

Step 6: Run setup upgrade command to install and enable the module: `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Step 7: Run compilation code command: `bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Step 8: Run deploy static content command: `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

You are done.

Comment: You can also try magento plugin for enhancing existing functionality of any Abstract class that means you can write your code :
$taxableAmount = max($rowTotal - $discountAmount, 0);
$discountTaxCompensationAmount = 0;
$rowTax = $taxableAmount * ($rate / 100);

By using afterYourMethodName() your code will go in this method.

Comment: For example : 
afterCalculateWithTaxInPrice{
// Your code goes here
}

Comment: @Oscprofessionals `calculateWithTaxInPrice` method is a protected method, so you can't use a plugin for that method.

Comment: Plugins and  overwriting Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation\RowBaseCalculator didn't worked for me. For quick fix i created patch and applied

Comment: @Anju I've updated my answer to include step-by-step to achieve your need, please check. In case you already installed your custom module, you must remove **generated** directory before running compile code command.